# Entity Framework: Could not load type on any new classes I add

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-power-tools

This is driving me crazy, I have spent hours trying to resolve it.

I am using Power tools for Entity Framework to view Entity Data Model.

All works fine with these two classes:

```
namespace MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer
{
    public class MarketMinData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Date { get; set; }
        public double Time { get; set; }
        public double Size { get; set; }
        // public int InstrumentID { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer
{
    public class Instrument
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Expiry { get; set; }
        public double TickSize { get; set; }
        public double TickValue { get; set; }
        public double OpenTime { get; set; }
        public double CloseTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the call to `DbContext`:

```
namespace MarketAnalyser.DataLayer
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<Instrument> Instrument { get; set; }
      //public DbSet<MarketMinData> MarketMinData { get; set; }
       public DbSet<MarketTickData> MarketTickData { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As soon as I add this class, or any other class I create or just try with any new class I write, I get an error.

New class:

```
namespace MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer
{
    public class MarketMinData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Date { get; set; }
        public double Time { get; set; }
        public double Size { get; set; }
        // public int InstrumentID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is going wrong and where to go; I've found nothing on StackOverflow or Google. I'm just lost on this.

Comment: what do you mean by error? do you get runtime exception or compiler error?

Comment: maybe your database doesnt fit the schema? please tell the exact error message you're receiving. also, since you added InstrumentID in MarketMinData, I assume it's going to be an FK, to utilize EF functionality you should also add the corresponding navigation property

Comment: Sorry, the error is :  Could not load type 'MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer.MarketMinData' from assembly......

Comment: But I dont get this with the other 2 classes and the references are the same. Also I dont think its a database schema problem as the error occurs when I just have that one class on its own.   I will add navigation once I have this problem solved. What is an FK ?

Comment: And I am getting this error when I try and View the entity data model

Comment: Could it be related to opening the project on a laptop running Visual Studio 2013 when I usually work with Visual studio 2015?